# I have a code for a menu like a game menu but the button when clicked does not go to the page

Tags: java, android, button, menu

public class SuperActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
     Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private Context SuperActivity;

            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.SuperActivity, Register.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }

     });

     Button Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Login);
     Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private Context SuperActivity;

            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.SuperActivity, Login.class);
                 startActivity(myIntent);
             }

     });

    };}
```

The code has only 2 buttons that I am trying to get to work right now. The code is establishing the buttons and is supposed to direct the user to the page when they click on a certain button: Register and Login are the buttons being used so I need to know am I missing something or is the code completely wrong in order to get the buttons to go to the designated page

Comment: What is the error you're getting? Off the top of my head, did you make sure the other activities are declared in your manifest?

Comment: Try removing both of `private Context SuperActivity;` and replace `this.SuperActivity` by `SuperActivity.this`.

Comment: The application has stopped unexpectedly is the error whenever I push both buttons... and yes they are declared in my manifest file

Comment: @Philipp I changed everything you said and it still doesnt work.. My logcat is saying something about my view.View.OnClick and java.lang.Class.getmethod

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace from logcat to your question, "something" isn't enough :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    private Context SuperActivity;

    public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.SuperActivity, Register.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    ...
```

You're declaring another SuperActivity class, but never instantiating it, then passing it down to the new Intent you're constructing.  Intent's constructor needs an *instance* of a context, you're passing down null.

To fix it, get rid of `private Context SuperActivity`, since you don't need it, and instead of passing `this.SuperActivity` in your Intent constructor, use `SuperActivity.this` instead, such as:

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        

    public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(SuperActivity.this, Register.class);
         startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    ...
```

Also note that `Register` in your original code isn't your button...

Comment: +1 but your terminology is off: There's no *class* being declared here, just a *field* with the very confusing name `SuperActivity` (to the OP: please check out the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)). That field isn't being *initalized*, so it's `null` which most likely causes the error when triggering the `Intent``.

Comment: @Philipp so what exactly do I need to do? Im relatively new at working in Eclipse...

Comment: Thanks Philipp!  @Shaye replace your onClickListener with the code in my answer.

Comment: @ShayeRobinson If this didn't help, please check my latest comment on your question.